# $3/7\leq {\frac {2-a}{3\,{a}^{3}+4}}+{\frac {2-b}{3\,{b}^{3}+4}}+{ \frac {2-c}{3\,{c}^{3}+4}} $

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and $abc\leq 1$ prove that:

$$3/7\leq {\frac {2-a}{3\,{a}^{3}+4}}+{\frac {2-b}{3\,{b}^{3}+4}}+{
\frac {2-c}{3\,{c}^{3}+4}}
$$

I was trying by separating $ (\sum \frac{2}{3a^3+4})-(\sum \frac{a}{3a^3+4})$

Now I need  to find the minimum value of $3a^3+4$. I do that by AM-GM as $3a^3+3+1 \ge 3^{\frac{5}{3}}.a$. But that is not doing any good. Do you have better methods?

Comment: First you need to find the equality case. It's $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: It's very hard even for $abc=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find an elegant way to do this, but tried with some brute force. This proof can be checked easily by a calculator. But checking it by hand seems to be too heavy work.

Set
$$f(x)=\frac{2-x}{3x^3+4}$$
and $g(x)=f(e^x)$. We get
$$f'(x)=-\frac{(3x^3+4)+9x^2(2-x)}{(3x^3+4)^2}=\frac{6x^2(x-3)-4}{(3x^3+4)^2}$$
$$g''(x)=-\frac{2e^x(18e^{6x}-81e^{5x}-78e^{3x}+108e^{2x}+8)}{(3e^{3x}+4)^3}$$
It's not hard to observe that the polynomial $P(x)=18x^6-81x^5-78x^3+108x^2+8$ has exactly two real roots $x_1\approx 0.901789,x_2\approx 4.64096$. We proceed to the following

> **Proposition 1.** $f(x)$ is monotone decreasing on $[0,3]$, and $f(x)>-1/81$ for $x\ge 0$.
>
> **Proof.** It's easy to see $f'(x)$ has a unique root on $x>0$, which we call $x_0$. It's obvious that $x_0>3$, and since $(3x_0^3+4)+9x_0^2(2-x_0)=0$, we have
>   $$f(x)\ge f(x_0)=\frac{2-x_0}{3x_0^3+4}=-\frac{1}{9x_0^2}>-\frac{1}{81}.$$
>
> **Corollary 1.** If $0<x\leq 1/6$, $y,z>0$, then $f(x)+f(y)+f(z)>3/7$.
>   **Proof.** By *Proposition 1* we have
>   $$f(x)+f(y)+f(z)-\frac 3 7\ge f(\frac 1 6)-\frac 1 {81}-\frac 1 {81}-\frac 3 7=\frac{571}{163863}>0.$$

The following two propositions follow from the convexity of $g(x)$.

> **Proposition 2.** For $x,y\in(0,x_1]$ we have
>   $$f(x)+f(y)\ge f(x_1)+f(\frac{xy}{x_1})$$
>   **Proposition 3.** For $x,y\in[x_1,x_2]$ we have
>   $$f(x)+f(y)\ge 2f(\sqrt{xy})$$

---

Now return to the original problem, we claim that

> **Claim.** If $\max(a,b,c)>4.6$, then $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)>3/7$.
>
> **Proof.** WLOG we may assume $a\le b\le c$. If $c>4.6$ and $b\ge 6/4.6=30/23$, then $a\le 1/bc<1/6$, hence we're done by *Corollary 1*. Otherwise $b<30/23$. We consider two cases.
>   *Case 1.* $b\ge x_1$. Then $a\le 1/bc\le 1/(0.9\times 4.64)$. By *Proposition 1* we have
>   $$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)>f(\frac 1{0.9\times 4.64})+f(\frac{30}{23})-\frac 1{81}>\frac 3 7+0.06>\frac 3 7.$$
>   *Case 2.* $b<x_1$. Then $a\le b<x_1$. By *Proposition 2* we have
>   $$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\ge f(x_1)+f(\frac{ab}{x_1})+f(c)$$
>   Now it's reduced to $b=x_1$, which has already been solved in *Case 1*.
>
> This concludes the proof.

Now it suffices to consider the case where $\min(a,b,c)\le 4.6<x_2$, which can be divided into four subcases:

*Case 1.* $a\le b\le x_1\le c<x_2$. By *Proposition 2* we have
$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\ge f(x_1)+f(\frac{ab}{x_1})+f(c)$$
Now it's reduced to $b=x_1$, which is to be solved in the following *Case 2*.

*Case 2.* $a\le x_1\le b\le c<x_2$. Apply *Proposition 1, 3* to reduce the problem to proving a polynomial inequality $2f(1/\sqrt{a})+f(a)\ge 3/7$ with the only variable $\sqrt{a}$. This one is easy to deal with. In fact it's equivalent to
$$\frac{(x-1)^2(2x^2+3)(24x^5+27x^4-6x^3-21x^2+4x+2)}{7(4x^3+3)(3x^6+4)}\ge 0$$
where $x=\sqrt{a}$.

*Case 3.* $a\le b\le c<x_1$. In this case $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)>3f(1)=3/7$.

*Case 4.* $x_1\le a\le b\le c<x_2$. Apply *Proposition 3* (or Jensen's inequality directly) to get the result.